# How can I prevent the flush arm in my toilet tank from getting under the flap?

Tags: toilet

I’ve taken the tank lid off and can see what is happening. The arm lever is getting caught under the flapper when you flush the toilet. It doesn’t matter how short or long I make the chain, the arm drops under the flapper and gets stuck.

You can jiggle that handle and it normally fixes it, but it seem like there is an adjustment I should be able to make to keep it from happening. Adjusting the chain length doesn’t seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

The arm shouldn't drop that low. I suspect that a part is broken. You can fix this a few ways:

- Replace the hardware. Overhaul kits are fairly inexpensive. You may be able to replace just the lever and arm to restore support.
- Devise a support for the arm. I have a pair of zip ties around the standing tube in one of my tanks for that purpose. The tails stick out and keep the arm from dropping too far. You could also create a wire hook and hang it on the tank edge. Don't use anything that would rust.
- Bend it. This is risky with plastic arms, but could be an easy fix.
- Rotate the standing tube and flapper away from the arm. This may require loosening a nut, so empty the tank first.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was lazy and just replaced the flapper, which got me pretty close. I think I’ll give the zip ties a try, can’t hurt

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: When bending plastics, heat (heat gun or hair dryer) can be helpful, but the caution remains - it's easy to break plastic.